# css3 transforms to simulate a present opening

Tags: css, css-transitions

Here my code :
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVPJwB

```css
/* Open Cube */
div#gift{
    margin-top: 0;
}
#origin {
    -webkit-perspective: 2500px;
    -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 250px;
    perspective: 2500px;
    perspective-origin: 50% 250px;
    margin: 200px auto;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
#origin #Ycube, #origin #Zcube {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
#origin #cube {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 613px;
    width: 604px;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100px 0;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-origin: 0 0 0;
}
#cube .one {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(200px);
    transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(200px);
}
#origin .face {
    position: absolute;
    height: 582px;
    width: 600px;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
    backface-visibility: visible;
    border: 1px #aaa solid;
}

#cube .two {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(286px);
    transform: translateZ(286px);

    transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
#cube:hover .two{
    transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px) translateZ(300px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin-x: 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin-y: 100%;
    background: red;
}
#cube .three {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(300px);
    transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(300px);

    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

#cube:hover .three{
    /*transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(300px);*/
    transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px) translateZ(-306px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin-x: 100%;
    -webkit-transform-origin-y: 100%;
}
#cube .four {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(-290px);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(-290px);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(-290px);
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(-290px);

    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
#cube:hover .four{
    transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px) translateZ(-300px) rotateX(90deg) rotateY(-0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin-x: 0%;
    -webkit-transform-origin-y: 100%;
}
#cube .five {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(300px);
    transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(300px);

    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

#cube:hover .five{
    /*transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(300px);*/
    transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px) translateZ(-306px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin-x: 0%;
    -webkit-transform-origin-y: 100%;
}
#cube .six {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(292px) rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(292px) rotate(180deg);

    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="codepen.css"/>
    <title>Calendar</title>
</head>
<body>
<section id="mainsection" role="main">
    <div id="origin">
        <div id="Zcube">
            <div id="Ycube">
                <div id="cube">
                    <div class="face two">
                    </div>
                    <div class="face three"></div>
                    <div class="face four"></div>
                    <div class="face five"></div>
                    <div class="face six"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer></footer>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

My question: Opening the cube, **why is each cube's face bottom side not attached to the base** during the animation?

At the start and at the end it's ok but not during animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply specify the [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) for the rotation  with :

```
.face{transform-origin:50% 100%;}
.six{transform-origin:50% 50%;}
```

This way all 4 faces will rotate arount the bottom edge and stay attached to the bottom face :

```css
/* Open Cube */
.face{transform-origin:50% 100%;}
.six{transform-origin:50% 50%;}
div#gift{
    margin-top: 0;
}
#origin {
    -webkit-perspective: 2500px;
    -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 250px;
    perspective: 2500px;
    perspective-origin: 50% 250px;
    margin: 200px auto;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
#origin #Ycube, #origin #Zcube {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
#origin #cube {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 613px;
    width: 604px;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100px 0;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-origin: 0 0 0;
}
#cube .one {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(200px);
    transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(200px);
}
#origin .face {
    position: absolute;
    height: 582px;
    width: 600px;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
    backface-visibility: visible;
    border: 1px #aaa solid;
}

#cube .two {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(286px);
    transform: translateZ(286px);

    transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
#cube:hover .two{
    transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px) translateZ(300px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin-x: 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin-y: 100%;
    background: red;
}
#cube .three {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(300px);
    transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(300px);

    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

#cube:hover .three{
    /*transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(300px);*/
    transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px) translateZ(-306px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin-x: 100%;
    -webkit-transform-origin-y: 100%;
}
#cube .four {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(-290px);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(-290px);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(-290px);
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(-290px);

    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
#cube:hover .four{
    transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px) translateZ(-300px) rotateX(90deg) rotateY(-0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin-x: 0%;
    -webkit-transform-origin-y: 100%;
}
#cube .five {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(300px);
    transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(300px);

    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

#cube:hover .five{
    /*transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(300px);*/
    transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px) translateZ(-306px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin-x: 0%;
    -webkit-transform-origin-y: 100%;
}
#cube .six {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(292px) rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(292px) rotate(180deg);

    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="codepen.css"/>
    <title>Calendar</title>
</head>
<body>
<section id="mainsection" role="main">
    <div id="origin">
        <div id="Zcube">
            <div id="Ycube">
                <div id="cube">
                    <div class="face two">
                    </div>
                    <div class="face three"></div>
                    <div class="face four"></div>
                    <div class="face five"></div>
                    <div class="face six"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer></footer>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```